# Абсолютная и относительная погрешность вычисления по схеме Эйткена

Tags: математика, численные-методы, интерполяция

Речь идет об **неустранимой погрешности** в вычисления по схеме Эйткена, но почему-то во многих источниках абсолютную погрешность считают как разность между истинной функцией f(x) и многочленом Лагранжа L_n(x) в точке(ведь это погрешность метода). Ну и сама неустранимая погрешность возникает из-за того что значения функции y_i=f(x_i) получены с некоторой погрешностью A_н.

Абсолютная и относительная погрешность для многочлена Лагранжа вычисляется как:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, где Ф_j коэффициент Лагранжа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С формулами для многочлена Лагранжа все понятно
**Как найти абсолютную и относительную погрешность вычисления по схеме Эйткена?**

Comment: Я не специалист, но мне показалось, что схема Эйткена, это алгоритм вычисления полинома. А погрешность считается для полинома относительно интерполируемой им функции. Но тогда говорить есть смысл только о погрешности для полинома, а не схемы. Для схемы может быть (не уверен) имеет смысл говорить о вычислительной погрешности, связанной с точностью задания входных параметров и точностью машинных вычислений.